# Hacer un calculo inverso con 3 input

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript

tengo 3 input para realizar un calculo, por ejemplo:

- a + a * ( b/100 ) = c
- c / ( ( b/100 ) + 1 ) = a

a,b,c son input distintos.

1. El primer calculo seria par c, pongo valores en a y b.
2. El segundo calculo pero inverso, es solo colocar valores en b y c y resultado en a.
   Dejo el código avanzado.

- form.component.html

  ```
           <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="venta">A<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="a"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="a"
                  formControlName="a"
                  #a
                  (keyup)="getA(a.value)"
                  [(ngModel)]="a"
                  style = "text-transform:uppercase;"

                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="kmTotales">B<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="b"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="B"
                  formControlName="b"
                  #b
                  (keyup)="getB(b.value)"
                  [(ngModel)]="b"
                  style = "text-transform:uppercase;"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="kmTotales">C<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="c"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="C"
                  formControlName="c"
                  #c
                  (keyup)="getC(c.value)"
                  [(ngModel)]="c"
                  style = "text-transform:uppercase;"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
  ```
- form.component.ts

  ```
  a: string = '';
  b: string = '';
  c: string = '';

  getA(val: string) {
      this.a = val;
  }
  getB(val: string) {
      this.b = val;
  }
  getC(val: string) {
      if (this.a !== '' && this.b !== '') {
      val = ((parseFloat(this.a) + (parseFloat(this.a) * 
      (parseFloat(this.b)/100))).toFixed(2)).toString();
      return this.c = val;
      } else if(this.a === '' || this.b === '') {        
     return this.c = '';
    }
  }
  ```

Mi pregunta y duda es saber como realizar un calculo a la inversa: c / ( ( b/100 ) + 1 ) = a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si esta respuesta ayudará... Pero me interesó el aspecto matemático de la pregunta.

Parece que las fórmulas detrás de la pregunta son correctas... Lo cual me sorprendió.

El problema que tienes, por tanto, es su aplicación. No conozco Angular en absoluto. No pude reproducir la aplicación desde la entrada HTML.

Creo que su error proviene de `.toFixed(2)`, lo que hace que pierda precisión en el resultado de `c`.

Así que lo cierto es que el cálculo matemático es bueno. Eso es todo lo que puedo aportar... Y eso es todo!! ;)

Aquí están mis pruebas usando escenarios.

```js
function doMath(a,b){
  a = parseFloat(a)
  b = parseFloat(b)
  return "" + (a + a * ( b / 100 ))
}

function undoMath(b, c){
  b = parseFloat(b)
  c = parseFloat(c)
  return "" + (c / ( ( b / 100 ) + 1 ))
}

const useCases = [  // Juse casos
  {
    a: "27.6",
    b: "51.2"
  },
  {
    a: "15",
    b: "7"
  },
  {
    a: "8",
    b: "3.3"
  },
  {
    a: "72",
    b: "84.87"
  }
  ,
  {
    a: "33.33333333",
    b: "666.666666"
  }
]

useCases.forEach((usecase) => {
  const c = doMath(usecase.a, usecase.b)
  console.log("c", c)
  
  const aa = undoMath(usecase.b, c)
  console.log("a original:", usecase.a, "aa calculado", aa)
  
  console.log(usecase.a === aa ? "Buen resultado." : "Diferencia")
  console.log("------------------------")
})
```